# Не выводить пустые ячейки mysql php,

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, помогите сделать запрос. Есть 4 столбца 1, 2, 3, 4 . Например в id 40 ячейка 2 пустая, нужно чтобы результат выводился так
Поле1
Поле3
Поле4

у меня выводится

Поле1

Поле3
Поле4

```
 <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `invlist` WHERE `id`=40");
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
do
{
echo "

".$data['1']."<br />
".$data['2']."<br />
".$data['3']."<br />
".$data['4']."

";
}
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($resultat));
?>
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: то есть чтобы не было пустой строки ячейки 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте при выводе, проверять пустая ячейка или нет

```
$result     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `invlist` WHERE `id`=40");
$data       = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

do{
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if( !empty($value) )
        echo "$value <br/>";
    }
}while($array = mysql_fetch_array($resultat));
```

тогда так

```
$result     = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `invlist` WHERE `id`=40");
$data       = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

do{

    if( !empty($data['1']) ) echo "{$data['1']}<br/>";
    if( !empty($data['2']) ) echo "{$data['2']}<br/>";
    if( !empty($data['3']) ) echo "{$data['3']}<br/>";
    if( !empty($data['4']) ) echo "{$data['4']}<br/>";

}while($array = mysql_fetch_array($resultat));
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, но мне нужно чтобы выводились только столюцы 1, ,2,3,4 , а не вся строка

Comment: @ЕвгенийМильке добавил второй вариант